What can trigger sleep/freeze on a nixos linux on display disconnection
I've got a Hystou home server which recently started to freeze immediately if the display is not connected. It started around the time of upgrade to 6.7.x, but can't place it exactly, currently running latest 6.8.x. Running on NixOS.
So far the following have been checked/enforced:

suspend/hibernation support disabled in bios
any options allowing fancy idle/s3 behaviour disabled in bios
systemd sleep settings explicitly disabled
no services related to power management are installed
hardware and software watchdog is configured to cause a reset, but never gets triggered
it's very unlikely to be a kernel oops (kdump doesn't trigger)
there's no serial port controller on this device
usb_debug is not available on this board (or I'm failing to start it up correctly)

What I definitely know:

no mention of sleep or shutdown in the logs
when I turn on the system, it starts up for at least 5 minutes before stopping (5 data points reported to a monitoring service)
it seems powered on, just unresponsive afterwards (I can hear the disk spinning)
reconnecting the display doesn't wake it up
there's no resource runaway behaviour before the freeze that I can see (processes, memory, temperature, cpu usage, etc. all seem normal)
when HDMI is disconnected, it takes 10s before the network connection dies
the system keeps working if I still have a keyboard connected to USB when the HDMI is unplugged

I'm trying to figure out what can trigger this behaviour at all on this system. What other areas am I missing?
